# Is there a WACG color contrast checker for terminal?

Tags: command-line, colors

I searched and found [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/11/gtk-app-check-contrast-ratio-linux/) post that shows how to install a color contrast checker for Ubuntu (for [WACG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/conformance)).

However, I want to be able to automate the color-checking process as part of a CI/CD pipeline.

Is there a terminal-based program for that operation?